# How to import description in wordpress with a csv file to show separate paragraphs after import but not a string of line?

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, import

Basically I am trying to import a csv file with new products and its description.
ALmost everything I need uploads without issues but description text appears as one string line.

Here's an example of my csv file:

[image: 1]

After I do import, the description text is uploaded like that:

This is description1;This is another paragraph2;This is another paragraph3

I would like this description text to look like that:

This is description1

This is another paragraph2

This is another paragraph3

How could I do this? Could anyone please help me with it and explain it easily?
Thank you!

Comment: What u use for export and import ?

Comment: I use importer WooCommerce products (CSV)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your CSV (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].